# Not getting the correct orientation of the user with respect to Kinect

Tags: algorithm, kinect, projection, angle

I am using Microsoft Kinect in a project. One of the task that I have to accomplish is to find the orientation of the user w.r.t the Kinect sensor (when the user turns, the orientation changes)
For this, I am trying to find the angle which the line joining the shoulders makes with the x axis of Kinect.

I have come up with the following code, but it gives me very small angle values, even when I turn almost about 40 degrees.

```
double vector_x=skel.SkeletonPositions[NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_SHOULDER_LEFT].x-skel.SkeletonPositions[NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_SHOULDER_RIGHT].x;
    double vector_y=skel.SkeletonPositions[NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_SHOULDER_LEFT].y-skel.SkeletonPositions[NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_SHOULDER_RIGHT].y;
    double vector_z=skel.SkeletonPositions[NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_SHOULDER_LEFT].z-skel.SkeletonPositions[NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_SHOULDER_RIGHT].z;
    double len1=sqrtf(vector_x * vector_x + vector_y * vector_y + vector_z * vector_z);
    double vector_x1=1.0;
    double vector_y1=0.0;
    double vector_z1=0.0; 
    double len2=sqrtf(vector_x1 * vector_x1 + vector_y1 * vector_y1 + vector_z1 * vector_z1);
    double dot_product = vector_x * vector_x1 + vector_y * vector_y1 + vector_z * vector_z1; 
    double angle = dot_product / (len1 * len2); 
    coor_left=Convert(vector_x)+"\t"+Convert(vector_y)+"\t"+Convert(vector_z)+"\n";
OutputDebugStringA(Convert(acos(angle)).c_str());
```

When I added the conversion of radians to degrees,

```
double angle1=angle*180.0/3.14;
```

I get values form -33 to -57(when I am facing the Kinect) and then to -33 again.

But in reality, it should be negative, then 0 and then positive on the other side. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. I realised that I was finding the angle between incorrect vectors.

All I needed to do was to take the projection of the left and the right shoulders on the x-z plane and then reduce the  problem to finding the angle between two vectors in a plane.

Here is what I did:

```
double CalcAngle(double p1x,double p1y, double p2x,double p2y, double p3x,double p3y, double p4x,double p4y)
{
//
// calculate the angle between the line from p1 to p2
// and the line from p3 to p4
//
double x1 = p1x - p2x;
double y1 = p1y - p2y;
double x2 = p3x - p4x;
double y2 = p3y - p4y;
//
double angle1 , angle2 , angle;
//
if (x1 != 0.0f)
angle1 = atan(y1/x1);
else
angle1 = 3.14159 / 2.0;  // 90 degrees
//
if (x2 != 0.0f)
angle2 = atan(y2/x2);
else
angle2 = 3.14159 / 2.0;  // 90 degrees
//
angle = fabs(angle2-angle1);
angle = angle * 180.0 / 3.14159;    // convert to degrees ???
//
return angle;
}

double myangle=CalcAngle(skel.SkeletonPositions[NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_SHOULDER_LEFT].x,skel.SkeletonPositions[NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_SHOULDER_LEFT].z,
        skel.SkeletonPositions[NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_SHOULDER_RIGHT].x,skel.SkeletonPositions[NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_SHOULDER_RIGHT].z,
        0,0,1,0);
        OutputDebugStringA(Convert(myangle).c_str());
    OutputDebugStringA("\n");
```